# Como jogar itens com um valor especifico para o inicio de um array?

Tags: javascript, array, classificação

Tenho um array perguntas[] com as seguintes propriedades:

```
perguntas[0] = { id:1; ordem: 3; inicio: 1 };
perguntas[1] = { id:2; ordem: 2; inicio: 0 }; 
perguntas[2] = { id:3; ordem: 1; inicio: 1 };
```

Gostaria de troca-los de ordem no array de acordo com a propriedade inicio. Onde 1 deve vir primeiro que 0.

Eu já utilizo uma função para ordenar de acordo com a propriedade ordem, só que essa ordenação seria secundária, dando prioridade ao itens com a propriedade inicio marcada como 1.

Como posso fazer isso?

O resultado esperado seria:

```
perguntas[0] = { id:3; ordem: 1; inicio: 1 };
perguntas[1] = { id:1; ordem: 3; inicio: 1 }; 
perguntas[2] = { id:2; ordem: 2; inicio: 0 };
```

Comment: A ordem esperada é mesmo essa, ou seria 3/1/2? Ou tanto faz 3/1 ou 1/3?

Comment: @bfavaretto Quando o AP fala em "ordenar de acordo com a propriedade ordem", assumo que seja em ordem crescente, na ausência de indicação em contrário. O resultado esperado estaria portanto correto.

Comment: Pode ser, mas fiquei confuso com o que é dito na primeira metade da pergunta. Não sei se a array dada ali já passou pela atual função de ordenação ou não. @mgibsonbr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer assim, seguindo as [indicações da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
var ordenada = perguntas.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.inicio > b.inicio) return -1;
    if (a.inicio < b.inicio) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Exmplo:

```js
var perguntas = [];
perguntas[0] = {
    id: 1,
    ordem: 3,
    inicio: 1
};
perguntas[1] = {
    id: 2,
    ordem: 2,
    inicio: 0
};
perguntas[2] = {
    id: 3,
    ordem: 1,
    inicio: 1
};

var ordenada = perguntas.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.inicio > b.inicio) return -1;
    if (a.inicio < b.inicio) return 1;
    return 0;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(ordenada, null, 2));
```

Repara que tens um erro de sintaxe nos objetos: deve ser `,` a separar as propriedades e não `;`

Comment: Note que a implementação padrão de `sort` **não é** necessariamente estável. Dependendo do ambiente em que esse código é executado, a ordenação por `inicio` pode invalidar totalmente a ordenação inicial por `ordem`. Nesse caso, a ordem relativa dos elementos com mesmo `inicio` é indefinida.

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu vi a sua resposta (e "upei") mas pela lista de browsers que a resposta que indicou nos browsers atuais isso não parece problema mais.

Comment: De fato, mas como o AP decidiu marcar essa resposta como aceita, achei importante deixar esse aviso aqui, para quem chegar a essa pergunta no futuro. Afinal, se não está no *standard*, não se pode confiar cegamente... :)

Comment: @mgibsonbr bem visto.

Answer (score 5):

Já temos boas respostas, mas segue uma versão que ordena por várias colunas, usando o `.sort` tradicional, caso alguém precise no futuro:

```js
var perguntas = [];
perguntas[0] = { id:1, ordem: 3, inicio: 1 };
perguntas[1] = { id:2, ordem: 2, inicio: 0 }; 
perguntas[2] = { id:3, ordem: 1, inicio: 1 };
perguntas[4] = { id:3, ordem: 4, inicio: 1 };
perguntas[3] = { id:1, ordem: 4, inicio: 1 };
perguntas[5] = { id:3, ordem: 5, inicio: 1 };

// Aumente o "peso" a cada coluna extra
// sinal( ) * 8, * 16, * 32 etc...
var resultado = perguntas.sort(function (a, b) { return (
  sinal( a.inicio - b.inicio ) * 4 +
  sinal( a.ordem  - b.ordem  ) * 2 +
  sinal( a.id     - b.id     )
); } );

// Math.sign não é suportado em todos os browsers, segue implementação local:
function sinal( i ) {
  return ( i > 0 ) - ( i < 0 );
}

// Essa parte aqui é só pra exibir o resultado para conferirmos:
for ( i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++ ) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + JSON.stringify( resultado[i] ) + '</p>';
}
```

No caso, basta por "pesos" nos ítens desejados, de forma que pese mais a diferença da coluna principal, mas se empatar, pesa mais o da segunta coluna, e assim por diante.

Por isso utilizamos potências de 2 nos pesos ( 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ), para garantir que os pesos das colunas inferiores somados nunca ultrapassem uma coluna superior.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar uma nova função de ordenação que faça uso da primeira:

```
perguntas = perguntas.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.inicio > b.inicio ? -1 : b.inicio > a.inicio ? 1 : comparadorAntigo(a, b);
});
```

Ou, se você tiver acesso a uma implementação [**estável**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o_est%C3%A1vel) (me parece que o `sort` padrão do JavaScript não impõe essa restrição, de modo que [os diferentes browsers implementam isso inconsistentemente](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3026281/520779)) você pode ordenar primeiro pela característica secundária, depois pela primária. Exemplo usando underscore.js:

```js
var perguntas = [];
perguntas[0] = { id:1, ordem: 3, inicio: 1 };
perguntas[1] = { id:2, ordem: 2, inicio: 0 }; 
perguntas[2] = { id:3, ordem: 1, inicio: 1 };

perguntas = _.sortBy(perguntas, "ordem"); // Ou seja qual for seu critério secundário
perguntas = _.sortBy(perguntas, function(x) { return -x.inicio; });

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(perguntas);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```